# Check for duplicate values in an array

Tags: c

I want to create this program:

A users enters 10 different values. But when a user enters the same value, the program gives a warning. I did something but it not working.

How can I create working algorithm for this program?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x,i,j;
    int dizi[10];

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d. number\n", i + 1);
        scanf_s("%d", &dizi[i]);

        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (dizi[j] == dizi[i])
            {
                printf("You have already entered this number");
            }
        }

    }

    printf("Entered numbers:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", dizi[i]);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are giving the warning decrease `i` by 1.
Otherwise you will not get 10 different number.

```
if (dizi[j] == dizi[i])
    {
        printf("You have already entered this number");
        i--;
    }
```

Inner loop with j should only check till i.

```
for( int j=0; j<i; j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the checking loop to

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

otherwise the check will check using uninitialised data.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    if (dizi[j] == dizi[i])
    {
        printf("You have already entered this number\n");
        --i;
        break;
    }
}
```